# Как воспроизвести аудио массив чисел с плавающей запятой

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу программу, которая должна воспроизводить звук, полученный путем генерации пачки синусоид с регулируемыми параметрами. Генерация не вызывает вопросов, однако появились проблемы с выводом.

На данный момент у меня есть массив чисел с плавающей запятой размера N. Этот массив имеет достаточный размер, чтобы уместился 1 период генерируемого сигнала. Обычно это не больше 100ms.
Всего 3 синусоиды, параметры для которых пользователь можем менять - это *амплитуда, частота дискретизации, несущая частота, длительность сигнала*.
Именно эти синусы должны воспроизводиться НЕПРЕРЫВНО, пока работает программа, т.е. цикл, что гоняет этот массив по кругу.

Пишу код на C#, имеется библиотека NAudio 2.0.1 Гуглил решения, но находил коды лишь для одной синусоиды.
Короче нужен пример реализации воспроизведения массива для 3х синусоид и, желательно, объяснение работы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Одну то получилось вывести? Покажите код.

Comment: Просто копировал код из этого источника https://markheath.net/post/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio

Comment: Не вижу проблемы запустить 3 воспроизведения одновременно. Звук смикшируется при выводе.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что нужно запустить этот код в разных потоках и в итоге звук будет единым?

Comment: Он и так многопоточный, можно просто сделать 3 запуска, без наворотов. В любом случае, вам никто не мешает попробовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ найден!
[Пример кода](https://markheath.net/post/playback-of-sine-wave-in-naudio)

```
    private static WaveOut waveOut;

    public class SineWaveProvider32 : WaveProvider32
    {
        int sample;

        public float Frequency1 { get; set; }
        public float Frequency2 { get; set; }
        public float Frequency3 { get; set; }
        public float Amplitude { get; set; }

        public override int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int sampleCount)
        {
            int sampleRate = WaveFormat.SampleRate;
            for (int n = 0; n < sampleCount; n++)
            {
                buffer[n + offset] = (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * sample * Frequency1) / sampleRate)) +
                                     (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * sample * Frequency2) / sampleRate)) +
                                     (float)(Amplitude * Math.Sin((2 * Math.PI * sample * Frequency3) / sampleRate));
                sample++;
                if (sample >= sampleRate) sample = 0;
            }
            return sampleCount;
        }
    }

    public static void GenerateSignal(int FrequencySin1, int FrequencySin2,int FrequencySin3)
    {
        if (waveOut == null)
        {
            var sineWaveProvider = new SineWaveProvider32();
            sineWaveProvider.SetWaveFormat(16000, 1); // 16kHz mono
            sineWaveProvider.Frequency1 = FrequencySin1;
            sineWaveProvider.Frequency2 = FrequencySin2;
            sineWaveProvider.Frequency3 = FrequencySin3;
            sineWaveProvider.Amplitude = 0.25f;
            waveOut = new WaveOut();
            waveOut.Init(sineWaveProvider);
            waveOut.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            waveOut.Stop();
            waveOut.Dispose();
            waveOut = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Harmont - круто, сам нашел ответ! Кстати, его можно, кажется, тоже отметить "принятым"-зеленая галочка рядом со счетчиком голосов

Comment: @S.H. самоответ вроде можно принять не раньше, чем через сутки после того как задан вопрос, или через двое суток, точно не помню.